# PostgreSQL ambiguous column reference after specifying column name

Tags: postgresql

I have a function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factors_apart_sa()
  RETURNS TABLE(surf_area integer, sa_factor numeric) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT factors_apart_sa.surf_area, factors_apart_sa.sa_factor FROM factors_apart_sa;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

After calling this function I get an error:

```
column reference "factors_apart_sa.surf_area" is ambiguous
```

How come is it still ambiguous if I have specified the table name.

Here is the table factors_apart_sa:

```
CREATE TABLE factors_apart_sa
(
  factors_apar_sa_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  surf_area integer,
  sa_factor numeric(19,4) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Isn't it because the function `factors_apart_sa` returns a table with column `surf_area`? Why the function and the table have the same name to begin with?

Comment: Thanks but when I change the function return value names it doesn't give me the error but I get only one column as a result. I need the result to be the a clone of the table without the PK column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table alias:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factors_apart_sa()
  RETURNS TABLE(surf_area integer, sa_factor numeric) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT f.surf_area, f.sa_factor FROM factors_apart_sa f;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

It is not a good idea to have the same names for a table and a function;

To call a function returnig set of rows place it in a `FROM` clause:

```
select f.* 
from factors_apart_sa() f;
```

Comment: This method returns me a table with one column. I need a returned table with two columns named "surf_area" and "sa_factor" because of the restrictions by existing java code.

Comment: No, you don't call the function properly. See the edited answer.

Comment: Right, but will this work when calling the function from java with the code: CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall(" { call factors_apart_sa() } "); ?

Comment: Unfortunately the java feature is for scalar functions.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I managed to test the CallableStatement in java and it does actually work.